# Using Types.NVARCHAR with oracle JDBC driver to work with Cyrillic chars

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, ora-17004

I am trying to use the ["New Methods for National Character Set Type Data in JDK 1.6"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/global.htm#BABJFAGA), to get a **standard JDBC** solution to handle cyrillic chars, but when the execution reaches any line with NVARCHAR type, for instance:

```
preparedSelect.setObject(3, "суббота", Types.NVARCHAR);
```

Then I get this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:131)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:197)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:490)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:7922)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:7502)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:7975)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:222)
```

I also tried to use setNString() but I get an even more strange exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setNString(ILjava/lang/String;)V
```

If I use java -Doracle.jdbc.defaultNChar=true myApplication with regular Types.VARCHAR, the Russian words are stored correctly. But using -Doracle.jdbc.defaultNChar=true is not an option since I'm working on a legacy application, I do not have control of running production environment, I'm just writing a component to it. Furthermore, this ["Readme for NChar How-to"](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/codesnippet/jdbc/nchar/readme.html) states that "This conversion has a substantial performance impact". So setting everything to NChar by default when only less than 1% of my tables needs this conversion in not a smart choice.

I'm using oracle thin driver and I have ojdbc6.jar and orai18n.jar in my classpath.

I'm looking for a standard JDBC solution. I can not use any methods or constants with "oracle" on them. OraclePreparedStatement is not an option for me.

I tried using Types.NVARCHAR with MSSQL Server and it runs fine.

Comment: Did you try using setNString() and see if it works?

Comment: I edited my question with an update about setNString()

Comment: To rule out the obvious: did you try to call the good old `setString()`? I have successfully stored arabic characters with that.

Comment: Yes I did. I only get upside-down question marks stored there ('¿¿¿¿¿'). This is because the default oracle charset is not UTF8. I have Oracle XE installed on my local machine and it stores fine using regular setString(). But I can't go asking more than 50 clients to change their default database charset, since they already have UTF16 for N-charset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution!

I was using ojdbc 11.2.0.1. When I switched to 11.2.0.2, I could get `setNString()` working properly.
 But I'm still getting the same `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type` if I use `setObject()` with `Type.NVARCHAR`. Shame on you Oracle...

Anyway, the solution: switch to ojdbc 11.2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work some time ago with the following incantations. These methods are an excerpt from a bigger class.

```
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0ProxyStatement;
import oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement;

    static {
        try {
            SET_FORM_OF_USE_METHOD = OraclePreparedStatement.class.getDeclaredMethod("setFormOfUse", new Class[] { Integer.TYPE, Short.TYPE });
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            LOG.fatal("Can't find the setFormOfUse method", ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }


    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session) throws SQLException {
        if (st instanceof OraclePreparedStatement) {
            ((OraclePreparedStatement)st).setFormOfUse(index, OraclePreparedStatement.FORM_NCHAR); 
        } else if (st instanceof C3P0ProxyStatement) {
            try {
                C3P0ProxyStatement c3p0St = (C3P0ProxyStatement) st;
                c3p0St.rawStatementOperation(SET_FORM_OF_USE_METHOD, C3P0ProxyStatement.RAW_STATEMENT, new Object[]{index, OraclePreparedStatement.FORM_NCHAR});
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                throw new UnexpectedException("Error calling setFormOfUse through C3P0", ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                throw new UnexpectedException("Error calling setFormOfUse through C3P0", ex);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                throw new UnexpectedException("Error calling setFormOfUse through C3P0", ex);
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unkown PreparedStatement implementation: " + st.getClass() + ". Maybe an unknown connection pool is hiding the OraclePreparedStatement?");
        }

        st.setString(index, (String) value);
    }
```

The nullSafeSet method is structured to work directly on OraclePreparedStatement instances, or on C3P0ProxyStatement in case you have the C3P0 connection pool; other options will have to be used in case of different pools.

This method worked with the ojdbc14.jar from Oracle 10.2.0.4.

Comment: The problem with this solution is because it is Oracle dependent. I am looking for something JDBC standard since our system works in both MSSQL Server and Oracle. Looks like Microsoft JDBC driver is more Java compliant than the Java "owner" itself.

Comment: As far as ojdbc14.jar is implied, there probably is no standard jdbc way to do it. I'm not sure about the driver version you are using; anyway, if this works, you could use it for oracle, and revert to the standard way for everything else.

Comment: As we can see in "New Methods for National Character Set Type Data in JDK 1.6" they say "use the setFormOfUse method... ...is discouraged because this method will be deprecated in future release" and they also say: "If the setObject method is used, then the target data type must be specified as Types.NCHAR, Types.NCLOB, Types.NVARCHAR, or Types.LONGNVARCHAR"